# how to pick middle text between 2 changing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

how to get center text `in yeshvanthpur , bangalore` , i,e `yeshvanthpur`  from

the string.

```
in[constant always] yeshvanthpur[changes every time] , bangalore [changes every time]
```

in above pattern `in` will remain constant every time. where as `yeshvanthpur` and `bangalore`  will changes every time.

question:  i want to get `yeshvanthpur`

**test cases:**

```
in yehlanka , bangalore  // expected output : yehlanka 

in bandra , mumbai     // expected output : bandra 

in mathikere , bangalore   // expected output : mathikere
```

please bear with me as i don't know `regex`

the only code i have

```
var str = 'in yehlanka , bangalore';
```

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: try this: var res = str.split(' ')[1]

Comment: clearify what you need. That is confusing me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**try this if in and , are gonna be constant**

```
var str = 'in yehlanka , bangalore';


str.split(',')[0].split('in')[1].trim() //output yehlanka
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what will be the trend of string in the varying space.

1. You cannot split using comma (',') as it can occur in the varying part of string.
2. You cannot split using 'yeshvanthpur' or 'in' or any other word as they can appear in the varying part again.

I would suggest using [NLP (Natural Language Processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) but you would need to study it to achieve accurate results.

Here is a [module](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural) for using NLP in node.js

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
var str = 'in yehlanka , bangalore';

var word = str.substring(3,str.indexOf(",")-1); //start index is 3 because 'in ' is a 3 char string
// last index is first occurrence of ',' 

alert(word);
```